# How to erase element from std::vector<string> by its length(erase not working)

Tags: c++

i have given a vector `

```
  vector<string> inputArray = { "aba","aa","ad","vcd","aba" };
```

and i want to return this vector which contains only string with the longest length, in this case i want to return only  `{"aba","vcd","aba"}`, so for now i want to erase elements which length is not equal to the highest `

```
vector<string> allLongestStrings(vector<string> inputArray) {

int length = inputArray.size();
int longstring = inputArray[0].length();
int count = 0;

vector<string> result;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (longstring < inputArray[i].length())
    {
        longstring = inputArray[i].length();
    }
    count++;

}

for (int = 0; i<count;i++)
{
    if (inputArray[i].length() != longstring)
    { 
        inputArray[i].erase(inputArray.begin() + i);
        count--;
        i--;
    }
}

return inputArray;
```

}

but i get this error `no instance of overloaded fucntion "std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::erase[with_Elem=char,_Traits=std::char_traits<char>,_Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list"` in `inputArray[i].erase(inputArray.begin()+i);` this line

what's wrong?

Comment: Note that this approach may skip some elements. Lets say the element at index 5 needs to be removed, then the value that used to be at index 6 will now occupy index 5. But since you've just checked that index, you won't check it again. If that element needs to be removed as well you will miss it.

Comment: You should erase from your array (std::vector), but you do it from your vector's element. I.e. it should be `inputArray.erase(inputArray.begin() + i - 1);` instead.

Comment: @vahancho oh, yes sir, that was a mistake, thanks for helping

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you mean, when i erase an element, other element's indexes are changing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom <- the idiomatic c++ way to do it

Comment: Rather than copy all & erase, you might want to consider `std::copy_if()` instead.

Comment: I'd use erase(remove_if) after finding the longest. It might be easier if you keep them sorted by length.

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan Yes. Removing an element from `std::vector` shifts all following elements to fill the gap. `std::vector` is a contiguous sequential container. It's `size()` is the number of elements it contains and is exactly 1 more than the largest index for those elements. This requires that is contains no index gaps.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so, what if after every time i erase element, i do i--; and count--; wouldn't it solve my problem?

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan Sure. Or only increment if you don't remove. You can also use iterators instead. `erase` returns a valid iterator to following the one removed (in this case where you remove single elements, it returns an iterator to the same position). Typically though people would use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux doesn't remove_if method demand a value?

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan `std::remove` demands a value. `std::remove_if` demands a unary predicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i achieved what i want using only erase, thanks for your time sir,appreciate it.

Comment: lots of extra copying of the vector. I'd strongly advise you to look at jakub_d's link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other problems, but this specific compiler message is telling you that's not the right way to remove specific character(s) from a string.

However, reading the question in the OP, we see that you wanted to remove a string from a vector. To fix that one specific error, simply change

```
inputArray[i].erase( /*character position(s) in the string*/ )
```

to

```
inputArray.erase( /*some position in the array*/ )
```

Or you could fix it so it uses an iterator in the string denoted by inputArray[i] to actually delete characters from that string, which of course isn't what you said you wanted to do. The point is, the error message is because you're using the wrong iterator type because you think that you're working with a vector, but you actually told it to work with a string that you got out of the vector.

And then you will compile and have other issues which are well covered in comments already.

Comment: I just realized someone did mention this in comments, early on. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `inputArray[i].erase(inputArray.begin() + i);` can be fixed as shown in [Kenny Ostrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766544/kenny-ostrom)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300823/4944425).

I'd like to point out that the OP could make use of the erase-remove idiom or even create a new vector with only the bigger strings instead (the posted code is already copying the source vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename InputIt>
auto only_the_longest_of(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    std::vector<value_type> result;

    // find the longest size
    auto longest = std::max_element(first, last,
        [](value_type const &a, value_type const &b) {
             return a.size() < b.size();
    });
    if ( longest == last )
        return result;

    // extract only the longest ones, instead of erasing
    std::copy_if( first, last, std::back_inserter(result)
                , [max_size = longest->size()] (value_type const& v) {
                    return v.size() >= max_size;    
    });

    return result;
}

template <typename T>
auto erase_the_shortest_from(std::vector<T> &input)
{    
    // find the longest size
    auto longest = std::max_element(input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
        [](T const &a, T const &b) {
             return a.size() < b.size();
    });
    if ( longest == input.cend()  ||  longest->size() == 0 )
        return input.end();

    // implement erase-remove idiom
    return input.erase(std::remove_if(
        input.begin(), input.end(), [max_size = longest->size()] (T const &v) {
            return v.size() < max_size;
    }));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test = {
        "aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"
    };

    // The original vector remain unchanged
    auto result = only_the_longest_of(test.cbegin(), test.cend());

    for (auto const& str : result)
        std::cout << str << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    // This will change the vector
    erase_the_shortest_from(test);

    for (auto const& str : test)
        std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort sir, but  i think i prefer it to be more simpler, like i have already shown